# How to manually enable android hardware acceleration after setContentView?

Tags: android, gif

In my SplashActivity, sometimes it will display a image view , and sometimes it will display gif. I use [android-gif-drawable](https://github.com/koral--/android-gif-drawable) to play gif. But I found, if I don't set activity `<activity android:hardwareAccelerated="true" />`, gif will play under normal rate. Only I enable hardwareAccelerated, it plays normal. However, after I set `<activity android:hardwareAccelerated="true" />`, I use `adb shell dumpsys com.yanzi.demo` found, GL cost about 20M memory. So, I must use java to enable hardware accelerate, only when play gif.

I use next code to enable it:

```
getWindow().setFlags(
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED);
```

write it before `setContentView` works well. But, it takes time for me to check whether play gif or not, so it must be enabled after `setContentView`. I test it, found don't work. Someone can help me? Or, this is a problem with no way? [Api guides](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html#controlling)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you enable hardware accelerated that way after `setContentView`, you must use `WindowManager` to add view. Otherwise， it will not work at all. Hope to help you.